# vagrant sets up duplicate IP addresses; Ansible picks them up?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I've got the following `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
NUM_HOSTS = 3

def hostname(id)
  "node#{id}"
end

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "chef/centos-7.0"

  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = false
    vb.memory = 512
    vb.cpus = 1
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "vagrant_playbook.yml"
    ansible.groups = {
      "vagrant" => (1..NUM_HOSTS).collect { |id| hostname(id) }
    }
  end

  NUM_HOSTS.times do |n|
    id = n + 1
    config.vm.define hostname(id), primary: id == 1 do |host|
      host.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.0.33.1#{id}"
    end
  end
end
```

This assigns the private addresses on `enp0s8`. However, it assigns duplicate IP addresses on `enp0s3`: `10.0.2.15`. Unfortunately, Ansible seems to be picking the duplicate address up in `ansible_default_ipv4` instead of the unique address, so services running on these boxes don't work as intended. So, is there a way to:

- stop Vagrant from assigning duplicate IPs? (I'm using the virtualbox provider, if that helps)
- change which interface `ansible_default_ipv4` uses?
- some other solution which I haven't thought to search for?

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround you can use in the meantime:

```
{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses | last }}
```

Will work assuming it's guaranteed that your ipv4 addresses for the target box will always be sorted in a predictable order.

Comment: It can work but it risky : must be sure to have that on all the environment.
No solution to execute a shell in vagrant that could force private network to be the default interface but having internet connection working ?